# Incomplete shapefile created by arcpy.Union_analysis()?

Tags: arcpy, union

When I attempt to use arcpy.Union_analysis() with 4 or more input files (all shapefiles; works with 3 or less) the operation is successful (no errors, exit code 0) but the final output is only the .sbn, .shx, and .shp.xml files (a few short of a shapefile set...).

If I watch my directory while the union is executing, I can see it creating the rest of the shapefile files (including the .shp) but right before the code completes, these files are deleted.

I've check my licence (arcpy.ProductInfo() = ArcInfo). I understand union is limited to 2 files if you have the basic licence. This is not the issue (it works with 3 files but not 4 or more and I don't get the 'you don't have the right licence' error).

I've replicated the issue on two machines with different, but valid, licenses.

Any solutions?

---

Code snippet is as follows. Unfortunately I cannot share the actual shapefiles.
arcpy code:

```
env.workspace = os.getcwd()
files = ['1.shp',
        '2.shp', 
        '3.shp',
        '4.shp', 
        '5.shp', 
        '6.shp',
        '7.shp', 
        '8.shp', 
        '9.shp',
        '10.shp', 
        '11.shp']

arcpy.SetProduct('arcinfo')
print arcpy.ProductInfo()
arcpy.Union_analysis(files, 'TestUnion', 'ONLY_FID')
```

I am using ArcGIS Version: 10.4.1, arcpy 2.7.10

With respect to a comment:

> "With ArcGIS Desktop Basic and Desktop Standard licenses, the number
>   of input feature classes or layers is limited to two."

We verified that we have the advanced license. This is not the issue. Also, it works with three files, proving this is not the issue since if it were we'd be limited to two.

We are trying the suggestion of converting to Geodatabases before the union since shapefiles are not known for their reliability. I'll update again if it works.

As shown in the code snippet, we tried with the JoinAttributes set to ONLY_FID. It still did not complete successfully.

How can we check where the problem is?

We also verified we are staying under the 2 GB shapefile size restriction.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  Could you please [edit] your question to include a snippet of your arcpy code that you've tried so that potential answerers can see how you've set it up and can test the same.  When you paste your code into your question, you can select it and press the **{ }** code button to format the code

Comment: What ArcGIS version are you running?

Comment: "With ArcGIS Desktop **Basic** and Desktop **Standard** licenses, the number of input feature classes or layers is limited to two."

Comment: Shapefiles are notorious for unreliable operation if the polygon topology is not valid. Try converting to file geodatabase.

Comment: You can set JoinAttributes to ONLY_FID. If this completes successfully, the geometry is good but you probably have duplicated field names or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the product to arcview, not arcinfo as explained in: 
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/setproduct.htm

This may be your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I apologize, the "arcview" was a remnant of my testing to verify this was NOT the issue. I updated the code snippet above to reflect this. Also, and interestingly enough, when I run arcpy.SetProduct('arcview') followed by print arcpy.ProductInfo() the output is "AlreadyInitialized" and "ArcInfo." So it seems like even though I specified the incorrect product, it defaulted to my "highest" product anyway. So unfortunately this is not the issue.